# Upserting in Mongo DB using official C# driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

In the official documentation of mongodb they mention upserts, so it would be really nice to write an upsert command instead of:

```
if (_campaignRepo.Exists(camp))
{
    _campaignRepo.DeleteByIdAndSystemId(camp);
}

_campaignRepo.Save(camp);
```

something which would implement that logic on the db level if it is possible. So what is the way to do an upsert if there is one?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The following code is from a working app:

```
weekplanStore.Update(
    Query.EQ("weekNumber", week),
    Update.Replace(rawWeekPlan),
    UpdateFlags.Upsert);
```

The weekplanStore is my MongoDB collection, and the code will update the document found with the query in the first argument or insert a new one if none is found. The "trick" is to use the UpdateFlags.Upsert modifier.

The rawWeekPlan is the object inserted or updated, and has the following type:

```
private class RawWeekPlan
{
    public ObjectId id;
    public int weekNumber;
    public WeekPlanEntry[] entries;
}
```

and turned into bson by the driver automatically.

Comment: Does it work for nested collections? Have you tried it out? Because it does not work for them in my case

Answer (score 83):

**Version 2** of the MongoDB C# driver requires setting the `IsUpsert` flag in the write commands. This example will upsert an entire document.

```cs
var newDoc = new BsonDocument { { "_id", 123 }, { "someKey", "someValue" } };
var result = await collection.ReplaceOneAsync(
                filter: new BsonDocument("_id", 123),
                options: new ReplaceOptions { IsUpsert = true },
                replacement: newDoc);
```

**Version 1** of the MongoDB C# driver implements this logic within the `Save` command.

```cs
var newDoc = new BsonDocument { { "_id", 123 }, { "someKey", "someValue" } };
collection.Save(newDoc);
```

> *The Save method is a combination of Insert and Update.* If the Id member of the document has a value, then it is assumed to be an existing document and Save calls Update on the document (setting the Upsert flag just in case it actually is a new document after all). Otherwise it is assumed to be a new document and Save calls Insert after first assigning a newly generated unique value to the Id member.

Reference: http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/1.11/driver/#save-tdocument-method

Note: This does require the proper mapping of the Id field however. More info on that here: http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/1.11/serialization/#identifying-the-id-field-or-property

Comment: This is no longer possible with the new API.

Comment: Updated. Although I think the new API made the upsert commands harder to use.

Comment: What gets passed to the filter if the newDocs ID is null, i.e. it's an insert? Just an empty bson document?

Comment: @BenCr if you're just doing a normal insert instead of an upsert then you should use the `InsertOneAsync` method. This doesn't require the ID field to be specified as MongoDB will create one during insert, but you can also create these IDs without going to the database just like a GUID so it's up to you. More info in the C# driver documentation here: http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.1/reference/driver/crud/writing/

Answer (score 44):

Starting from v2.0 of the driver there's a new async-only API. The old API should no longer be used as it's a blocking facade over the new API and is deprecated.

The currently recommended way to upsert a document is by calling and awaiting `ReplaceOneAsync` with the `IsUpsert` flag turned on and a filter that matches the relevant document:

```
Hamster hamster = ...
var replaceOneResult = await collection.ReplaceOneAsync(
    doc => doc.Id == hamster.Id, 
    hamster, 
    new UpdateOptions {IsUpsert = true});
```

You can check whether the operation was an insert or an update by looking at `ReplaceOneResult.MatchedCount`:

Comment: I am trying to use ReplaceOneAsync but it throws an exception :"Element name ' 'is not valid  ", i am using the filter for updateOneasync it works but not with replaceone  . can you please help me?

Comment: UpdateOptions is obselete, use 
    new ReplaceOptions {IsUpsert = true});
now

Comment: I get this error - Expression not supported: doc.Id in (doc.Id == "4222460e-eabc-446c-a4d9-51504f9f25ba") because field "_id" is not represented as a string.

Comment: Ok it works after removing this attribute from the Id field - [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]

Answer (score 6):

You can use the regular update command, but just pass it the Upsert update flag

```
MongoCollection collection = db.GetCollection("matches");
var query = new QueryDocument("recordId", recordId);

var update = Update.Set("FirstName", "John").Set("LastName","Doe");
matchCollection.Update(query, update, UpdateFlags.Upsert, SafeMode.False);
```

That code is adapted from a working application (shortened for clarity)