# Performing an effcient upsert in mongodb

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

I have the following C# model class:

```
public class Thingy
{        
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }        
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime TimeCreated { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public string UUID { get; set; }
}
```

and the following ASP.MVC controller action:

```
public ActionResult Create(Thingy thing)
{
    var query = Query.EQ("UUID", thing.UUID);
    var update = Update.Set("Title", thing.Title)
        .Set("Content", thing.Content);

    var t = _collection.Update(query, update, SafeMode.True);
    if (t.UpdatedExisting == false)
    {
        thing.TimeCreated = DateTime.Now;
        thing.UUID = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        _collection.Insert(thing);
    }

        /*
        var t = _collection.FindOne(query);

        if (t == null)
        {
            thing.TimeCreated = DateTime.Now;
            thing.UUID = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            _collection.Insert(thing);                
        }
        else
        {
            _collection.Update(query, update);                
        }
        */
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```

This method either does an update or insert.  If it needs to do an insert, it must set the UUID and TimeCreated members.  If it needs to do an update, it must leave UUID and TimeCreated alone, but must update the members Title and Content.

The code that's commented out works, but does not seem to be most efficient.  When it calls FindOne, that is one trip to mongodb.  Then if it goes to the else clause, it does another query and an update operation, so that's 2 more trips to mongodb.

What is a more efficient way to do what I'm trying to accomplish?

Comment: See [Upserting in Mongo DB using official C# driver][1] for information on C# MongoDB upsertting.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7240028/upserting-in-mongo-db-using-official-c-sharp-driver

Comment: @slee: Yes, I saw that and other reference/tutorials from mongodb site.  Please re-read my question.

Comment: Mongo has completely changed the interface between the 2 dll release he did... :S

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the linked SO answer, for upserts to work, you need to update the entire document, not just a few properties.

Personally I would separate the `Create` and `Edit` into separate MVC actions. SRP. Creating a `Thingy` has different considerations from updating it.

If you still want to do an upsert instead of separate insert/update calls, you will need to use the following code:

```
_collection.Update(
    Query.EQ("UUID", thing.UUID),
    Update.Replace(thing),
    UpsertFlags.Upsert
);
```

The question now becomes, how do we ensure the `thing` has the appropriate values for both cases, ie insert as well as update.

My assumption is (based on your code model binding to a `Thingy` instance), your view is sending back all fields (including `UUID` and `TimeCreated`). Which implies, in case of an update, the view already has the values pre-populated for `UUID` and `TimeCreated`. So in the case of a `Thingy` being updated, the `thing` object has the latest values.

Now in case of an create, when the view is rendered, you could store `DateTime.MinValue` for the `TimeCreated` field. In your `Create` MVC action, you could check if `TimeCreated` is `DateTime.MinValue`, then set it to current time and also store a new value for `UUID`.

This way, in the case of a insert as well, the `thing` has the latest values. We can thus safely do an Upsert.

Answer (score 0):

I take this approach when doing upserts for Mongo from the controller

```
public ActionResult Create(Thingy model)
{
    var thing = _collection.FindOneAs<Thingy>(Query.EQ("UUID", model.UUID));
    if(thing == null)
    {
       thing = new Thingy{
                         TimeCreated = DateTime.Now,
                         UUID = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                         Id = ObjectId.GenerateNewId()
                        }
    }
    else 
    {
       thing.Content = model.Content;
       //other updates here
    }

    _collection.Save<Thingy>(thing);
    return View();
}
```