# When I use ReplaceOneAsync and IsUpsert = true mongodb add's a null Id. How do I stop this?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb-csharp-2.0

I am able to update a Document if the Document Exists using the Following

```
var filter = Builders<Neighborhood>.Filter.Eq(x => x.Id, neighborhood.Id);

var result = await collection.ReplaceOneAsync(filter,
             neighborhood,new UpdateOptions { IsUpsert = true });


[CollectionName("neighborhoods")]
[BsonIgnoreExtraElements(true)]
public class Neighborhood : IEntity<string>
{
 [BsonId(IdGenerator = typeof(GuidGenerator))]
 [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
 public string Id { get; set; }

 [BsonElement("name")]
 public string  Name    { get; set; }
}
```

How do Insert a Document if the Id = NULL and I want to return the updated result.

When Inserting a New Document `NULL` ID, A Record is created with a `NULL` Id, I added  `[BsonId(IdGenerator = typeof(GuidGenerator))]` without any luck.

What am I doing wrong so a `ObjectId` can be generated for new records.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Upserting in Mongo DB using official C# driver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7240028/upserting-in-mongo-db-using-official-c-sharp-driver)

Comment: I modified the question, this issue is related to the Object Id not be generated

Comment: This is not a duplicate

Answer (score 11, accepted):

C# Driver thinks that Id is already filled. You need to add settings for Id field which allows driver to generate new Id.
There are two approaches:

1. Add attribute `[BsonIgnoreIfDefault]` in your `Neighborhood` model.
2. Setup in code

   ```
   BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<Neighborhood>(x =>
   {
       x.AutoMap();
       x.GetMemberMap(m => m.Id).SetIgnoreIfDefault(true);
   });
   ```

I prefer the second approach because you don't need to add reference to MongoDB.

MongoDB API proposes two methods:
1) `ReplaceOneAsync` returns `ReplaceOneResult` which has `UpsertedId` property

```
var filter = Builders<Neighborhood>.Filter.Where(x => x.Name == "somthing");
var replaceResult = await collection.ReplaceOneAsync(filter, entity, new UpdateOptions { IsUpsert = true });
return replaceResult.UpsertedId;
```

2) `FindOneAndReplaceAsync` allows you to select what you want - entity before changes or after. For our task we need after

```
var filter = Builders<Neighborhood>.Filter.Where(x => x.Name == "somthing");
var options = new FindOneAndReplaceOptions<Neighborhood, Neighborhood>
  {
     IsUpsert = true,
     ReturnDocument = ReturnDocument.After
  };
var updatedEntity = await collection.FindOneAndReplaceAsync(filter, entity, options);
```

Comment: Thanks, This Should help, Still not getting the Id to Generate, there may be other issues I need to look at

Comment: @SPS101, try `FindOneAndReplaceAsync`. I added an example to the answer.

Comment: Thanks, for the help, For Some Reason on Save the Id is generated, but on other commands the Id is not generated, So I am manually setting the objectId when  null, still a work in progress but I can move forward. Thanks Again

Comment: Neither `FindOneAndReplace` or `ReplaceOneAsync` will set the the `[BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]` property, even with the `[BsonIgnoreIfDefault]` attribute.