# MongoDB and C# - Checking if document exists, if it doesn't insert it

Tags: c#, mongodb, upsert

I currently get a list of 50 restaurants from the Yelp Fusion API. I want to save these restaurants in my database for further use in my application.

Since I get this list based on the user's coordinates, it's possible the API will return restaurants that are already in my database. To prevent duplicates, I check if the restaurant ID provided by yelp already exists in the database. If it's already in my database, it won't insert that restaurant.

I'm using a MongoDB database.

I accomplish this using the following function:

```
public async static void CheckSubjects(List<Subject> subjects)
    {
        SubjectRepository rep = new SubjectRepository();
        List<Subject> insert = new List<Subject>();
        foreach (var item in subjects)
        {
            if (!rep.SubjectsExists(item).GetAwaiter().GetResult())
                insert.Add(item);
        }
        if (insert.Count > 0)
            await rep.CreateAllSubjects(insert);
    }
```

In this function a subject is a restaurant. The repository is the class which communicates with the database.

This is my function that checks if the restaurant already exists:

```
public async Task<bool> SubjectExists(Subject sub)
    {
        var result = await db.Subjects.Find(Builders<Subject>.Filter.Eq("yelp_id", sub.yelp_id)).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        if (result != null)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
```

You can see it's very performance heavy to make 50 calls to the database to see if it already exists. I did some research and found the upsert function from MongoDB. I just don't know how I could use this in my scenario.

Could anyone help me out with this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using upsert as an option during an update, if a document doesn't exist, it will be created. Instead of trying to find each restaurant ans then insert them, you could call an [update](https://docs.mongodb.com/getting-started/csharp/update) for each of them with upsert set as true (I think it'd be something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7240028/upserting-in-mongo-db-using-official-c-sharp-driver))

Another aproach that could be even more efficient would be setting `yelp_id` as a key by creating an [unique index](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/core/index-unique/), then when inserting duplicated entries it would fail, so you wouldn't need to worry if it is already in the database.

Comment: Wouldn't calling an upsert for each restaurant be bad for performance?

Comment: I think it would be just a little better that it is now, as you would loop just once. But I think the second approach would be much better.