# Azure DocumentDB with MongoDB .NET driver: how to set id manually?

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I'd like to upsert json document as below code;

```
string CollectionName = "Collection";

MongoClientSettings settings = MongoClientSettings.FromUrl(
  new MongoUrl(MongoDbConnectionString)
);
settings.SslSettings =
  new SslSettings() { EnabledSslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12 };
var mongoClient = new MongoClient(settings);
var db = mongoClient.GetDatabase(MongoDbDatabaseName);

var collection = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(CollectionName);

// id that I want to set.
var id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
var _id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

JObject jObject = new JObject(
    new JProperty("id", id), // Id test 1
    new JProperty("_id", _id), // Id test 2
    new JProperty("property1", "value1"),
    new JProperty("property2", "value2"));

BsonDocument newDoc = BsonDocument.Parse(jObject.ToString());

// upsert reference: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7240028/361100
var result = collection.ReplaceOne(
    filter: new BsonDocument("id", jObject["id"].Value<string>()),
    options: new UpdateOptions { IsUpsert = true },
    replacement: newDoc);
```

The `id` is the value I want to set manually, but the result is as below;

```
{
  "$id": "0106669b-9670-4547-a2a3-f7ea800fac0d", // Id test 1
  "_id": "9eb71b3e-83be-4dd9-b037-269d59cbe5e4", // Id test 2
  "id": "9a0a4b90-5be7-44b7-af05-e3bbe08dc25e", // system generated
  "property1": "value1",
  "property2": "value2",
  "_rid": "I2ECAKbBewAEAAAAAAAAAA==",
  "_self": "dbs/I2ECAA==/colls/I2ECAKbBewA=/docs/I2ECAKbBewAEAAAAAAAAAA==/",
  "_etag": "\"0000d277-0000-0000-0000-590c557a0000\"",
  "_attachments": "attachments/",
  "_ts": 1493980531
}
```

My `id` value is placed in `$id` property which is not I expected, and the property `id` in document is generated by the system.

**NOTE**
I tested both `id` and `_id` but all of them are not set as DocumentDB `"id"`.

DocumentDB .NET library allows to set `id` by myself if I only put the property name `id`. How to do it with MongoDB .NET driver?

Answer (score 1):

In MongoDB, the id of the document is "_id" and not "id".  To get the expected behavior, you need to add a new JProperty with name == "_id".

```
JObject jObject = new JObject(
    new JProperty("_id", id),
    new JProperty("id", id),
    new JProperty("property1", "value1"),
    new JProperty("property2", "value2"));
```

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insert/#insert-a-document-specifying-an-id-field

Comment: As I said, `_id` does not recognized as `id` in DocumentDB. The _real id_ is automatically generated.

Comment: @Youngjae, are you using MongoDB drivers to read the document as well?   "Id" is a special property in DocumentDB and is always set to the string representation of "_id". The Mongo layer converts the user-specified "id" to "$id" while storing but converts it back to "id" before returning the result via MongoDB interface

Comment: I read the data only from AzPortal browser as I will only use MongoDB driver for writing purpose and will read by using DocDB .Net driver from other jobs. So, is there no way to set _real_ DocDB `id` manually from MongoDB driver?