# Mongodb Update or insert in c#

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to update or insert into to mongo collection "Member". Under this collection i have an  array MagazineSubscription. Here magazine Code is unique. Please refer the sample JSON.

So if need to update or insert into mongo using C# mongo driver.

1. First I need to check this code exist
   2, If it exist  update one
2. If it does not exist insert.

Is there any way I can do in one step. Like if it already exist update otherwise insert. Instead of hit twice. Because my collection is very big.

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c44f7017en0893524d4e9b1"), 
    "Code" : "WH01", 
    "Name" : "Lara", 
    "LastName" : "John", 
    "DOB" : "12-10-2017", 
    "Gender" : "Male", 
    "Dependents" : [
        {
            "RelationShip" : "Son", 
            "Name" : "JOHN", 
            "DOB" : "01-01-1970", 
            "Gender" : "Male", 
            "Address" : "Paris", 
            "ContactNumber" : "+312233445666"
        }, 
        {
            "RelationShip" : "Wife", 
            "Name" : "Marry", 
            "DOB" : "01-01-1980", 
            "Gender" : "Female", 
            "Address" : "Paris", 
            "ContactNumber" : "+312233445666"
        }
    ]
    "Matrimony" : [
        {
            "Fee" : 1000.0, 
            "FromDate" : "01-01-2015", 
            "ToDate" : "01-01-2017", 
            "Status" : false
        }
    ], 
    "MagazineSubscription" : [
        {
            "MagazineCode" : "WSS", 
            "DateFrom" : "01-05-2018", 
            "DateTo" : "01-01-2020", 
            "PaidAmount" : 1000.0, 
            "ActualCost" : 1500.0, 
            "Status" : false, 
            "DeliveryStatus" : [
                {
                    "ReturnedDate" : "10-01-2019", 
                    "Comment" : "Returned because of invalid address"
                }, 
                {
                    "ReturnedDate" : "10-02-2019", 
                    "Comment" : "Returned because of invalid address"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use mongodb's update operation with upsert:true.
Please refer here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/

Here's a sample from the page:

```
 db.collection.update(
   <query>,
   <update>,
   {
     upsert: <boolean>, //you need this option
     multi: <boolean>,
     writeConcern: <document>,
     collation: <document>,
     arrayFilters: [ <filterdocument1>, ... ]
   }
)
```

And here's a similar question according to what you need:
[Upserting in Mongo DB using official C# driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7240028/upserting-in-mongo-db-using-official-c-sharp-driver)

**EDIT 1**

Steps:

1. First you need to write a filter to scan if the document exists. you can check any number of keys (Essentially a document).
2. Write the update section with the keys you'd like to update (Essentially a document).
3. Set upsert to true.

Mongodb will use your filter to search the document. If found, it will use the update section to perform the update mentioned by you.

In case the document does not exist, a new document will be created by using the filter keys + keys in the update part.

Hope that makes things clear as I have never used a C# mongo driver. So I won't be able to provide you the exact syntax.

**EDIT 2**

I'm providing @jeffsaracco's solution here:

```
MongoCollection collection = db.GetCollection("matches");
var query = new QueryDocument("recordId", recordId); //this is the filter

var update = Update.Set("FirstName", "John").Set("LastName","Doe"); //these are the keys to be updated
matchCollection.Update(query, update, UpdateFlags.Upsert, SafeMode.False);
```

Comment: The link  contain the  query which i can execute in shell. What i want is not a query . I am looking for something which i can achieve in c# by using c# mongo driver.

Comment: Here i need to use then BSODocument to include in Filter? I am little confused. How we can use the refered link . ? MagazineSubscription.MagazineCode is the filter condition while adding the item to MagazineSubscription . Can you please update an example code from C# code  referring  my sample JSON.

Comment: THanks for the explanation . I am able to do it in shell . My question is how to achieve it in c# not through shell. The example shown in EDIT2 is just one level and it is very simple case. My case i need to update magazine subscription. Please refer my json and update your EDIT2. Then you may get where i am  stuck.

Comment: https://jacekstyrylski.github.io/2018/02/01/MongoDB-Update-array-element-net/  But when i enable IsUpsert=true . I Get position error.

Comment: This is the error i get "The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query."